# How can I distinguish between a system process PID and a user process PID?

Tags: objective-c, macos, unix

Using objective-c on OSX how can I distinguish between the PID of a user application (i.e. Safari) and a system process? (i.e. launchd)

I basically need to be able to take in a PID as input and display whether its a user application or a system process as output.

Answer (score 1):

The PID is not what is used to distinguish between "user" and "system" processes. The distinguishing factors are who (which user account) started it and how/where/when it was started. On Linux (other Unix-like OSes, including OSX, aren't that much different), things running under the "root" account or a certain number of other special purpose accounts can loosely be considered "system" processes, while those started by accounts that correspond with actual human users would be considered "user" processes, but the lines are very blurry. It's probably not as useful a categorization as you might think it is...

Comment: If you open Activity Monitor, you will find for some processes, an icon beside the process name. I have found that processes with these "icons" seem to meet my classification of "Applications". What criteria does a PID have to meet to have an "icon" beside its's process name?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with all of twalberg's comments.

You can operationalize your understanding by looking at the output of `ps -ef` run from the command line. (Terminal.app).

You can `ps -ef | grep -i safari` to see if anything unique is returned. Same for other "user" apps.

Also try

```
ps -ef| awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c
```

to see the spread of ownership for all processes.

Understand this before you spend time trying to code something in objective-c.

IHTH

Comment: If you open Activity Monitor, you will find for some processes, an icon beside the process name. I have found that processes with these "icons" seem to meet my classification of "Applications". What criteria does a PID have to meet to have an "icon" beside its's process name?

Comment: Is the icon a generic icon, or something specific to the application? Almost certainly something in a cfg file, or an application resource (compiled in). An objective-c person will have to answer that question.  Good luck.